# How to actually run mozilla openbadges

Tags: node.js, openbadge

I'm following this tutorial here.

https://github.com/mozilla/openbadges-badgekit/wiki/BadgeKit-Self-Hosting-Guide#badgekit-api-configuration

It says, when you run the API use this command source env_local

The problem is, I'm new to node and not really sure how I run the API. I've downloaded all the stuff, installed node, and got a simple hello world program working with node. I just don't know how I actually run the API. I thought I had to run the procfile, but when I do node procfile I get an error saying cannot find module badegkit\badgekit-api\start

As a hacky ass solution, I figured this out. I tried setting PATH in environment variables to env_local, as well as doing SET path = env_local in the command window and neither worked. However, if you browse to the badgekit api folder then app then lib, there's a db.js file in there.

Here's what I did, their stuff is commented out.

```
var options = {
  driver: 'mysql',
  // host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  // user: process.env.DB_USER,
  // password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  // database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  user: "username",
  password: "password",
  database: "dbname",
}
```

Just put in your mysql creds and then you can run the db migrate. Obviously this isn't ideal as anywhere else that uses env is still going to be screwy, but it got me to step 2.

**2014-09-29 Edit**
For all those curious, as of right now, node isn't really supported on windows per se. I ran into so many issues with python and gyp, that I ended up just spinning up a linux box in hyper v and hosting it there.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind that command is to load the environment variables setup in `env_local`. By deafult, they are set up as a few `export` commands, which should put the key=value pairs into your running environment.

I actually removed the export strings and stored them as `.env_dev`, so a file with:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_NAME=badgekitapi
...etc...
```

And the command I used to run things was: `nf start -e .env_dev`

With the API running, and able to store badges, you can now follow the tutorials to run `openbadges-badgekit` - so you can actually make and issue some badges ; )

Good luck!

Comment: So help me out here. I'm trying to set my source with node but I can't I'm on windows and if I do

Node

source env_local

I just get this http://i.imgur.com/sR6QHkl.png. How do I set my source so I can run the db migrate file?

Comment: In Windows, you could set up the environment variables at the system level (like where you would set the `PATH` variable), or just that command window with `SET variable=value`. Once those are set, I would expect NodeJS to pull out the value in the same way when running.

Comment: So you're saying before running node do something like SET source=env_local? Or running a node window then doing that? Sorry, this is all new to me.

Comment: Before running node you must set the environment variables, as that node application is looking in the environment it is running in to get values. Something like `SET DB_HOST=localhost`(for all the variables) before you run node.